# Analytics for a single method in VueJS with apm elastic search

Tags: javascript, vue.js, elasticsearch, vuejs2, apm

I have been trying to integrate apm agent for VueJS into my app, and I cant seem to analyze a single method with apm spans. All I can succeed doing is getting the render time [with their tutorial which works.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/rum-js/master/vue-integration.html)

I am trying to create a span just for a single method. What I tried:

```js
// component..
methods: {
    makePreview(e) {
      this.span = this.$apm.startSpan('makePreview', 'custom') 
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = e => {
        this.fileContents = e.target.result;
      }
      reader.readAsText(e);
      this.span && this.span.end()
    },
    // rest of functions..
```

Which results in nothing in Kibana's ui, the only span I can see is 'create-mount-duration' from their tutorial.
If someone can provide a working example or a solution I would be glad. Thanks in advance.